# JUnit test for JSF validator

Tags: java, jsf, junit

I have this simple Java method which I use to test input from JSF page.

```
public void validateDC(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException, SQLException
    {

        Double d;
        String s = value.toString().trim();

        if (s.length() > 10)
        {
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "  Value is too long! (18 digits max)", null));
        }

        try
        {
            d = Double.parseDouble(s);
            if (d < 0)
            {
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "  '" + d + "' must be positive number!", null));
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe) { d = null; }


        if (d != null)
        {


        }
        else
        {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        s.isEmpty() ? "  This field cannot be empty!" : "  '" + s + "' is not a number!", null));
        }

    }
```

I'm interested how I can write JUnit test for this validator? I can simply call it and pass argument but there is no return value. What are the possible solutions?

Comment: The general contract for validation methods is described in the [Validator javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JUnit4, you can use this:

```
@Test(expected=ValidatorException.class)
public void testValidatorException() {
 //call to trigger the exception   
 validateDC(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some samples I have written to give you an simple idea about how you can test your method.

```
@Test(expected = ValidatorException.class)
  public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenValueLengthIsGreaterThan10() throws Exception {
    Validaor validaor = new Validator();

    FacesContext context;
    UIComponent component;
    Object value;// <-- I don't know what value exactly is. But you have to create one with length less than 10  of its toString() value
    validaor.validateDC(context,component,value);

  }




  @Test
  public void shouldNotThrowExceptionWhenValueLengthIsLessThan10() throws Exception {
    Validaor validaor = new Validator();

    FacesContext context;
    UIComponent component;
    Object value;// create object with length more than 10 chars to of its toString() value
    validaor.validateDC(context,component,value);

  }
```

Hope this was helpful .

Comment: You cannot tell by an excerpt of code that the name of the method is not that obvious. And why is the name of the Exception not that good? ValidationException does tell it is a validation error. What do you want? It is a validation error with extra info (value too long, must be positive number, ...). But good examples, altough already given in first answer by someone else.

Comment: In netbeans I get error into the imports. I imported `import org.junit.Test;
import sun.security.validator.ValidatorException;` but still I need to import other package because I get error here `Validaor validaor = new Validator();

        FacesContext context;
        UIComponent component;`

Comment: @PeterPenzov don't just copy/paste the code, you should read and understand it, also understand that people can make mistakes like writing `Validaor` instead of `Validator` (note the **t** difference).

Comment: As a recommendation: first help OP to solve the problem, then add your opinions about the code provided as your recommendations not as rants about OP.